# How can I find mean for same value column? in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe, and I am trying to find mean of stars for each name

```
  Name  stars  
0   A      5
1   A      5
2   B      3
3   C      2
4   B      4
5   B      2
6   B      2

Output:
       count mean stars
    A   2     5.00
    C   1     2.00
    B   4     1.57
```

Comment: The expected output  is not correct for `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the dataframe by `Name`, then apply `len`, and `np.mean` aggregates on `stars` column.

```py
>>> df.groupby('Name')['stars'].agg(**{ 'count': len, 'mean stars': np.mean})

      count  mean stars
Name                   
A         2        5.00
B         4        2.75
C         1        2.00
```